# Cannot enter check out date in China Visa itinerary Section 2.6

Tags: visas, china, applications, itineraries

Section 2.6 Itinerary in China (in time sequence) of [Visa Application Form.pdf (V. 2013)](http://www.china-embassy.org/eng/visas/fd/W020130830801798289342.pdf) doesn't allow entering check-in and check-out dates for a single address row. I can only enter a check-in date. Trying to type more than the format of yyyy-mm-dd pops up an alert with the format rule.

Are we allowed to just put a single date for the Visa application? Example 2019-01-01 Hotel, Beijing, China? I would expect to be allowed to enter 2019-01-01 to 2019-01-07 Hotel, Beijing, China.

Edit: I'm using Adobe Reader to fill the PDF out.

Comment: I think the assumption is that you are going to account for every night, so the check out date from your first hotel will appear as the check in date at the next one.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: You're probably right, although it doesn't make much sense - it's a large country and overnight travel (e.g. on sleeper trains) is common.

Comment: I think the posted answer has actual facts. I've only done a very simple China visa application, several years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The check in and check out dates are supposed to be on different rows on the form.

This is to ensure you can check in and out of different places with over lapping dates for example:

Check in at hotel 1 day 1
Check in at hotel 2 day 2
Check out at hotel 1 day 3

You get the picture, this is not very common but the form handles all types of travel and stays that’s why

Comment: In your example, what would be your location in the night between days 2 and 3?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper either hotel 1 or 2 there are very special use cases where this is applicable, I don’t want to market our company services here but we have encountered this at least 4-5 times in the last 2 years for people where we assist with visa and work permit services

Comment: Well, the form says just "date", not "check in date", which may just as well refer to the date of arrival at the respective location. The idea of departing from hotel 1 after already having arrived at hotel 2 sounds a bit confusing. I wonder whether there's a canonical way of expressing the kind of alternative itineraries you seem to describe.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper welcome to China, you will also find that if you ask 10 government officers about how to fill in the form you get 11 answered and most likely neither is fully correct

Answer (score 1):

The check in and check out dates are supposed to be on different rows on the form is probably the right answer. I'm posting what got me a visa/worked for me as well.

I used Preview on a Mac to insert text for the check in and check out dates for a single address. E.g

2019-01-01 to 2019-01-14

for the date cell; I used the form for the address side. No questions from the officer.